# Removing debugging messages in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have couple of mysql queries in PHP and at the end of each query I did this

```
mysql_query(STRING) or die(mysql_error());
```

This is fine as far as I am in DEV environment but I dont want production users to see these errors. Any good Idea to remove this messages by just setting `ON OFF.`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even easier you could just replace all `die(` with `error_handle(` or something else, and include this function:

```
function error_handle($err) {
    die($err); // Comment this line out if you don't want the error to be displayed.
}
```

This is also great because you could extend the code to log errors etc in production. You could in addition define a `$debug`-variable somewhere in your global code if you are using Git or other version-control-systems.

**Edit:** I suggest replace all `die(` and not just `die` to avoid replaces where you don't want it, if you e.g use die in a sentence or something.

Comment: @OptmiusCrime all suggestions are very good but this is very handy and easy to mantain.. Thanks

Comment: @user1765876 - Me, keeping it simple since 2001.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that you shouldn't use `mysql_` as they're deprecated, you can simply make another function:

```
define('DEV', true);

function mysql_query_custom() {
    $result = call_user_func_array('mysql_query', func_get_args());

    if ($result === false) {
        if (DEV) {
            die(mysql_error());
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

mysql_query_custom(STRING);
```

Answer (score 1):

Lots of ways to do it.  The most terse and most like you're doing now:

```
// do this once
$PRODUCTION = true;

// now use
mysql_query() or ($PRODUCTION ?: die(mysql_error()));
```

I caution though this is not a maintainable way to debug in the long term.  There's a lot of good alternatives in this thread.

Whatever you do, **develop a comprehensive error detection, logging, and response mechanism** in your code.  If you're using a framework, leverage its facilities.

Answer (score 0):

Then set a configuration variable called `$DEBUG` and just wrap your logic in a conditional `if`/`else`?

```
$DEBUG = true;

if ($DEBUG) {
  mysql_query(STRING) or die(mysql_error());
}
else {
  mysql_query(STRING);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const DEBUG = true;

function fail($message) { die (DEBUG ? $message : ''); }

...

use_mysql_query_even_though_it_sucks() or fail(mysql_error());
// seriously.  Use mysqli.
```

Comment: `use_mysql_query_even_though_it_sucks()` haha

Answer (score 0):

Better still, use something like this:

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] != "dev.mydomain.com"){
    ini_set("display_errors",0);
    ini_set("log_errors", 1);
}
```

It saves you having to remember to disable the errors when you upload it to the production server.